# Uniqueness of graph embeddings on surfaces for highly connected graphs

Tags: graph-theory, surfaces

A theorem of Whitney says that if $i_1$ and $i_2$ are two embeddings of a 3-connected planar graph into $S^2$, then there exists a homeomorphism $h : S^2 \to S^2$ such that $h \circ i_1 = i_2$.

Is there a known analogs of Whitneys theorem for other closed surfaces?

For example for the torus, is there a known natural number $t$ such that if a toral graph $G$ is $t$-connected, then up to homeomorphisms of the torus the embedding of $G$ on the torus is unique (or does such a $t$ exist, possibly without being explicitly known?)?  Similarly, I would be interested in such results for the projective plane or other surfaces.

Comment: Note that for each surface there is a limit on the connectivity of graphs that embed on it. In fact, for each surface only a finite number of graphs of connectivity 7 or more can embed on it.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Thank you for your comment, I was not aware of that result -- could you possibly provide me with a reference?

Comment: [This](https://doi.org/10.1006/jctb.1997.1809) is an old paper which discusses this and gives reference. I'm not too familiar with recent work.